# Is there a general definition for the kernel of a differential equation?

Tags: operator-theory, heat-equation

Let the Heat equation
\begin{align}
 u_t&=\Delta{u}\text{ in }\mathbb{R}_{+}\times \mathbb{R}^n\\
u(0)&=u_0
\end{align}

The heat kernel is $p_t(x)=\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}\exp\left( -\frac{|x|^2}{4t}\right)$ and this kernel satisfies $\int p_t(x)\,dx=1$, $p_t$ is positive and $p_t$ is smooth $\mathbb{R}_{+}\times \mathbb{R}^n$ and satisfies the heat equation.

From what I have studied, another way to represent the kernel of the heat equation is by using the Fourier transform, that is, $p_t(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mathrm{e}^{ix\cdot \xi}\mathrm{e}^{-t|\xi|^2}\,d\xi$ then $p_t$ is a Schwartz function because $\mathrm{e}^{-t|\xi|^2}$ is a Schwartz function and how the transform is an automorphism on the Schwartz function, then $p_t$ is a Schwartz function etc.

In general, if
\begin{align}
u_t&=Pu,\quad t>0\\
u(0)&=u_0
\end{align}
with $P$ an differential operator.

What is the definition of an kernel for the operator $P$?

This kernel must always satisfy that $P_t$ is smooth, $P_t$ positive and $\int P_t=1$? or does this change according to each differential equation?